# How to make Gwibber notifications clickable?

Tags: notification, gwibber

One of the accounts that I have in Gwibber is my Twitter account. It nicely shows every now and then notifications with the new twits.
Whenever a twit has a link (URL) within it I feel an urge to click on the link withing the notification to directly open it within a browser. However, it seems like notifications are not clickable and when hovering over them they just become opaque.

Is there a way to make those links clickable?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, notify-osd does support this. However, gwibber does not send notifications with the necessary hints to require interaction. And the way notify-osd handles it, may not be what you want. The way this is handled in Unity, is that gwibber adds itself to the Messages indicator, and you click on there to open the gwibber UI, when you get a notification, if you wish to do that.

To make gwibber do it, even if you switch to notification-daemon instead of notify-osd, you will need to patch the code in gwibber to add the necessary hints of interactivity, to the notifications themselves.

Answer (score 1):

`notify-osd` doesn't support this (by design). The old notification system (`notification-deamon`) did support this if the application said it was possible.

You can remove `nofify-osd` and install `notification-deamon` and (if I'm reading thinsg right) it should just work. Notification Daemon is set to take precedence over NotifyOSD.

There is an [old thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663840) about needing to play around with `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` but the script now suggest this is all accounted for. I only mention this as a reference if things don't go to plan :)

---

But even if you do get it to work, there's no indication that Gwibber's notifications  will be clickable - They may have pulled legacy support for the old notification framework.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a new version of notify-osd (the package that shows notifications)

Comment: Are u being sarcastic?

Comment: This should be suggested upstream to the developers