# How to enable clickable notifications for pidgin?

Tags: notification, pidgin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Gwibber notifications clickable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115134/how-to-make-gwibber-notifications-clickable)

I want to make the notifications ballons for pidgin clickable, so I can click on it and it should take me throgh direct to the chat window.

Is this possible?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I asked a [very similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/115134/22263) in the past.
Take a look at the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Guifications via Synaptic Package Manager,

[image]

Once Installed go to "Tools/Plugins and choose "Guifications",activate it and click on "Configure Plugin" in order to set your preferences. You can set the position, stack, and other display options, the same as Mouse behavior.

[image]

Additionally you can set which notifications you want to be notified about and get themes to enhance your GUI notifications.

*Note: You might need to disable current notification popups in order not to receive duplicated notifications.*

Good luck!