# Can I click away notifications (notify-osd)?

Tags: 12.10, unity, notify-osd

Is it possible to click away those fancy notifications?
 Often I have to wait until those bubbles vanish and that's quite unproductive.

PS: Using currently 12.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no. By design you are unable to close them (with a click, at least).

But if that really annoys you I have read sometime ago an article on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org) showing how to install a patched NotifyOSD version and a configuration tool to make them clickable. Those packages are provided through a PPA, so the usual pitfalls on using them apply(1).

Those PPA's have packages to Quantal, so if using a PPA is ok to you give it a try. I personally have never used them, so I cannot tell how stable they are or not. If something goes wrong you can use `ppa-purge` to revert the changes.

[Configurable NotifyOSD Bubbles For Ubuntu: Move, Close On Click, Change Colors And More ~ Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html)

[(1) Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/33871)

Answer (score 0):

`notify-osd` is locked down because developers know best, right?

However you can still [install `notification-daemon`](https://askubuntu.com/a/115145/449) (which was replaced by `notify-osd`) and after logging out and in again, you should see *functional* (albeit clunkier in design) notifications.

Comment: See the section on 12.10 [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/88648/25656). `xfce4-notifyd` comes with little close buttons visible when one hovers over the bubble.